# How to export ADT certificate to facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, apache-flex

I have a flex android mobile application and I want to implement facebook's SSO.

I was reading facebook's android SSO tutorial and it said:

> "You need to put your Android application signature into your Facebook app settings."

My application's signature was generated by ADT certificate:

> adt -certificate -validityPeriod 25 -cn SelfSigned 1024-RSA file.pfx mypassword

But facebook suggests using keytool to export the key and that apparently requires an alias. Because doing the command below gives me an alias not found error:

> keytool -exportcert -storetype pkcs12 -keystore file.pfx -storepass mypassword

How am I supposed to export my certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good trick for doing this is to not do this (hah!), and let it fail (you will need to have the facebook app installed, it's not used if it falls back to the web auth). When it fails, it prints the key into the logcat output, and you can just get it from there and put it into your facebook application settings.